# Наложение одного блока на другие

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.

Подскажите как сделать чтобы выпадающие подпункты меню накладывались сверху на другой?

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/qgA5V/)

Если навести на "пункт меню2" то отображается нормально, потому что внизу элементов уже нет.

Если навести же на "пункт меню1" то подпункты отображаются, но вместе с ним и основные пункты меню.
Как сделать чтобы они перекрывали собой остальные элементы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробуйте [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/fdAq4/). Нет времени разбираться, но мне кажется, что можно было бы все сделать аккуратней. Ощущение, что вы спешите и не очень продуманно действуете.

Answer (score 0):

Поиграйтесь с настройками css, в частности [`z-index`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index).

Comment: Ставил z-index

Comment: ну вот я сделал 

.menu ul li.item {position: relative; z-index:6; border-bottom: 5px solid #FFF4DA; height:38px; float:left; position:relative;}

и пункт меню1 стал виден... так же и с остальными надо...

Comment: Что-то не могу понять, навожу на "пункт меню1", появляются подпункты меню, но на них также нельзя навести курсор.

Comment: Я хочу чтобы не пункт меню1 был виден, а подпункты перекрывали пункты основного меню и ина них можно было навести курсор